# Anyone can tell me how to fix this, place holder, and error

Tags: android

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ImageView ImageMenuUtama = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backgroundDpn);
    Picasso.with(this).load( "http://cloudofoasis.com/api/Ivan/Gambar/bkgutama.jpg")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .fit()
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .into(ImageMenuUtama);

}
```

and this picture show the code error
placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) and error(R.drawable.error):

[image: placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) and error(R.drawable.error)]

Comment: your `placeholder` is in `drawable` directory ? are you sure

Comment: What error you are getting? Show the proper error

Comment: @bardao : iam very newbie, what u mean?

Comment: @VicJordan : look the picture  in the link above, sry bad english

Comment: In the project explorer open `res` folder and expand all the subfolders, `drawable` , `layout`, `menu`... and check where your `placeholder` is. `R.drwawable.palceholder` means `placeholder` is inside `res/drawable` directory. Do the same for `R.drawable.error`

Comment: if doesnt exist then just create placeholder.xml and error.xml in drawable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add image with name "placeholder" and "error" in drawable folder

**STEP TO ADD DRAWABLE** :

1. Copy image from your computer
2. Right click on drawable folder and click paste

   [image: drawable folder]
3. Choose drawable directory

   [image: drawable directory]
4. Give it name "placeholder", and click ok

   [image: give it name]

Comment: owh thx u. try it now